# Can a PWA simulate anything that can be done with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, progressive-web-apps

I know that react native is for cross-platformed mobile apps and that ReactJS is for web apps. However, If I want to build effective mobile apps do I have to learn react native or can I just learn ReactJS and convert it to a PWA and let it be equally as effective. I wonder if the PWA method can simulate anything that can be done with react native, or is it restricted by certain factors and really not as powerful as react native.

Answer (score 1):

A PWA like any other web app, only has access to the APIs supported by the web browser. Where as native applications have access to the native APIs provided by the platform. As a result of this, no; a PWA cannot do everything that can be done by a React Native app.